Being honest with rejection vs. preparing applicant for future possibility
I know we've had these topics before but I need a fresh perspective going into 2025.
I am part of a hiring team in an IT company which is working on new hiring methodologies and pipelines. Our firm places extreme importance on "empathy" at all levels of employment. My understanding of empathy has always leaned more to 'putting yourself in another person's shoes'. Albeit, with the understanding that nobody is an 'empathy expert' (maybe least of all us 'IT nerds') and that we're all always trying to do better.
In the hiring team the topic came up - what to do with candidates which are clearly not a fit for a position (one way or another). Which highlighted a very strong push from other team members, that in this case we should "nurture" them for the potential possible future chance in x, y years. That this would also build 'good brand image' etc.
Except I believe there's an elephant in the room. An applicant is applying for a job primarily because they want the job now, not to be prepared for a possible job years down the line.
Holding off on rejecting them, I argue risks seriously alienating them. In fact, I think this is the opposite of empathy. Instead of thinking about the applicant and their situation, we would instead focus on anticipating a "need" that I feel the candidate likely might not even have. In doing so, I think there's a real risk of being condescending, even pitying toward them and otherwise alienating them. In short, I believe it has the real potential to blow up in our faces. It would of course be another thing altogether, if the candidate themselves reached out to us for advice.
Of course no hiring pipeline is perfect and we are trying to make ours a lot better. But I feel like the tsunami of complaints I have seen from people in the last decade. Of employers wasting applicant's time and not just being upfront and honest, is just too much to ignore in this case. Coupled with the constant feedback that people these days generally go into job interviews wanting transparency and honesty before most else. Putting someone through additional talks for really any reason, if they were not the one who asked. In my opinion just builds false hope when in the pipeline we've already decided among ourselves in the firm to not hire this person.
For my concerns I've now been hit with various 'personal incredulity' replies and other team-mates have lashed out against me and asked for anecdotes to back up my concern. So I've now been given the task of basically coming up with legitimate evidence of such complaints against employers because certain people in my company haven't personally observed these. I want to completely avoid all the drama associated with this so I came here in the hopes to learn myself if my concerns are unfounded or misplaced. At the very least how to nurture applicants without insulting them...
So how to reconcile therefore treating applicants humanely, fairly and honestly when they are not a clear fit. Versus the extreme team insistence of nurturing/mentoring an applicant for a future position and to build a good image of our brand.
EDIT: Personally I would argue the second goal has little to do with our hiring process, but I don't get to make that decision and after a battery of condescending remarks both here and in the team already regretting even mentioning this.
EDIT 2: I really should have mentioned that 85% of the people in our hiring pipeline already have 10 years of professional experience, and our median experience in our firm is 22.6 years. Which is part of why I argue there is a real risk of insulting someone who is already an established professional just to try and sell them the potential for a future job later and be "nice guys".

Aside: please consider not using the term "grooming". If you don't know why, see e.g. this link. (Content warning: sexual abuse)

To be clear, when you say “mentoring”, you mean effectively not hiring them right now but somehow keeping in contact to guide them towards a possible job years down the line? Why do you feel that conflicts with being honest? What exactly would they see this mentoring entails? ( directing them to certain courses, someone actively working with them, …?)

This question, while interesting, seems kind of opinion based, but also, could you explain what you mean by 'nurture' ? There's a big difference between advising to them (e.g.) to do certain training courses etc. and give them false hope that you'll hire them then, than saying something like "sorry you weren't successful on this occasion but we'll keep your CV on file".

Ambiguity over whether a candidate is actually rejected; appeal to ethics and empathy; apparent unawareness of the subtextual implications of certain language; steadfast disagreement with the majority on all this including "Reddit-tier" demands to back up oneself with anecdotes - could this be somehow related? https://www.reddit.com/r/tifu/comments/1gza31d/tifu_by_leaving_after_being_told_id_be_called/

I think we need more info on what this nurturing process actually entails. You’re not rejecting the candidates but you’re also not making them an offer so what are you saying to them exactly? There’s a pretty big difference between “feel free to reapply in the future” and “learn x, y, and, z and then we can begin your onboarding.”

If a person is not a fit now, why in a few years? And how much are you willing to invest in somebody who will work for somebody else in the meantime?

(A) "Our firm places extreme importance on empathy" (B) "My understanding of empathy has always been [..]" If your firm places extreme importance on this, why is your personal definition relevant here, and not what the firm considers to be the thing that's so important to them? (C) "My understanding of empathy has always been close to its definition" sounds like a veiled way to say "I'm more right about my interpretation than they are about theirs", which is subjective at best and  I'm still left wondering why only your interpretation is relevant to the question at hand?

There's a lot of presumptuousness here and even tone policing. I'd like to remind this is my first ever question and I don't know really where to begin with answering most replies. @Flater I didn't say I had my own definition I said my own "understanding" of empathy leans more toward putting yourself in another person's shoes. Whereas my firm seems to understand it as anticipating the applicant's needs or desires. I am more inclined to agree with *jmoreno that the applicant will 'likely' forget about us years down the line and our own firm will change a lot in that time. Also what *Donald said

@AffableAmbler I think a lot of the problem here is that this process for us seems to start anywhere in the pipeline. It could be right at the start if we detect a bad fit, or after a considerable amount of time has passed and effort has gone into interviews which has the greater potential to lead to sourness. We always give a reason for rejecting an applicant but this topic came up in the first place when we DID clearly decide NOT to hire someone internally, but instead the decision was made to STILL schedule another meeting with someone again face-to-face to "hopefully" 'nurture' them.

Can you clarify if this "Nurture" policy is for internal only, external only, or all job candidates? There is a massive difference between wanting to "nurture" an internal candidate vs an external candidate. One is career development, the other is friendzoning an applicant.

Are we talking about a situation where someone applied for job A, you think he's not a good fit for that job, but might do great in position B, yet you have enough people doing B right now? Or about someone applying for a job, and you find he's not a good fit for your company at all and you will probably never employ him? In the first case, asking them if they are interested in future possibilities is fine (and it's also fine if they say no). In the second case, that is something I would consider lying.

@PhilipKendall “the practice of preparing or training someone for a particular purpose or activity.” It’s a perfectly appropriate word to use here. Yes, it has (relatively recently) developed a negative meaning too, but are you going to walk into a horse stable and insist they stop using the word because of that?

When someone uses a word with a well-known and extremely negative connotation, and they accuse others of "tone policing" for politely suggesting to not use that, I can't help but assume they're trolling. Even giving the benefit of the doubt, it suggests caring more about being able to say whatever one wants, in the way one wants, rather than caring about the effects one's words have, and making even the smallest accommodation in line with that.

My immediate reaction whenever I hear an overemphasis on buzzwords like "empathy" is to assume that the person talking doesn't actually practice the concept. "...other team-mates have lashed out against me..." Oh, look, there it is. This feelings-oriented garbage is typically just a facade to make people feel better about not doing the right thing and trying to convince everyone around them about how good they are in spite of it.

I think it depends on situation: an applicant who freshly graduated from university might appreciate this kind of feedback, while it might very well alienate a candidate on a more senior level. It also depends on you as employer, e.g. if your company is highly sought after (FAANG, Microsoft, SAP), this might not come across as condescending as much as if you were some random tech firm. "Empathy" would be necessary to assess each situation individually and choose to go this way or leave it - a general ruling that is always applied is not empathetic at all.

we should "nurture" them for the potential possible future chance -- Huh?  Your company is seriously going to spend time and money "nurturing" non-employees?

That seems all overly complicated. What's wrong with being open and just telling the truth? Something like

Hey Sydney, unfortunately we decided to go into a different direction. However, we really did like your application and candidacy. Would it be ok if we keep your resume on file and reach out as soon as another suitable opportunity emerges?

I don't know what else there is to "groom". You really can't do anything meaningful unless you have another open req to hire against in which case you can fast track the process a bit.
If things intersect later again: great! If not: that's fine too: no one made any commitments or promises so no harm no foul.
There is no better way to ruin your brand and wreck candidate relationships then by being dishonest. Lying about the rejection is pretty much the worst you can do.

The question is about "what to do with candidates which are clearly not a fit for a position (one way or another)." Then if the response is "However, we really did like your application and candidacy" isn't helpful. Would rather get a honest response with a point or two why I wasn't picked in the first place.

@RenatoIvancic there is no reason you can't do both; provide the feedback for this position and say we'd like to keep you on record for future roles

@RenatoIvancic: In 90% of the cases its quite simple:. There were more than one viable candidate so they rank ordered and you didn't come in as #1. If Alice hadn't shown up, you would have gotten the gig, but Alice did show up and they were a better fit. Could be any number of things, specific skills, experiences, cultural fit, comp, communication style, etc. Its very specific to that role, you and Alice and there is little to be learned here. Employers don't disclose this because it typically just leads to pointless arguing and potential discrimination accusations.

@Hilmar This is how I WANT the process to go, but my concern here is that so much of how we hire is run on gut feelings. We add stages that we don't all agree on and follow a team-members 'gut feeling' a lot more than I like. My philosophy is always giving a clear rejection that shows honesty, transparency and respect, with the initiation to talk about it and get more feedback if they wish. In this case the applicant gets a quick, clear answer with an outstretched hand. Instead it feels like my firm would risk scheduling further talks with people which risks leading them on. I disagree there

I should probably be more "unfortunately we don't feel this position is adequate for you. However...". Possibly with pointers on things you feel the candidate should work on (but that could backfire in that they could do what you ask for — or at least attempt to — and come back 3 months later with a very small effort in that direction rather than 3 years later when they have actually completed the necessary work).

@questionasker. Than it feels you are trying to solve the wrong problem. I suggest putting effort into fixing your hiring process. A process that doesn't come up with a clear answer in a reasonable amount of time is bad for everyone involved. There is no good way of "stringing people along" other then "don't do it".

The difference of being nice vs kind. Nice is not telling someone they won't get the job because its not nice to tell people no. Kind is telling them they didn't get the job because they want to know as soon as possible if they are going to get the job.

Letting someone know that they aren't a good fit for a specific job isn't mean. Telling them what skillset or experience they lack would help them if this really their desired career path.
Leaving someone with false hope is IMHO worse.
I personally hate the phrase "go in another direction". That isn't being as straightforward as possible. "Other candidates are stronger in the skills we need" or "Other candidates have more experience in the areas that are critical to us" are less sugar coated. This way the candidate can have a conversation about how to get the skillset and/or experience required for your company's needs.
Anything less isn't setting you and them up for success.
As to the concept of grooming, that is hiring someone at a lesser role and giving them the opportunity to grow. Hiring someone and then hoping that they will grow into the position that they have been hired for is unfair to the other team members. Teaching junior team members is expected. Teaching your peers that aren't qualified is a drag on resources. How is that a good idea?

I think you misunderstand. In this case the candidate was a perfectly good fit for the role, but there was another candidate that was an even better fit. Since there is only one open req, only one person can be hired. Why that other person was in this specific case a better fit for this specific role is a pointless discussion. There is little to be learned, this was just the luck of the draw.

@Hilmar I didn't intend to reference your answer. My point is that the person on the receiving end of  phrase, could use more info. Not about the person hired, but about what they can focus on to be the next person hired.

@Hilmar actually in our case the applicants are often the only one in their hiring pipeline (eg. for Role A, B or C). We actually try our best to not have applicants actually ever go up against each other because we need so many different skills. In this case the applicant was just not a good fit at all very early in the process and this person was in a pipeline I am responsible for. I wanted to reject them quickly and fairly with an invitation to get more feedback if needed. The hiring manager wanted to have yet another face-to-face which I argued was not fair when we had decided on a no.

@questionasker - Your experiences reaffirm my point. And congrats on being able to attract / retain talent (reading your edits to the OP). That doubles down on not wasting their time with puffery.

Your edit

I really should have mentioned that 85% of the people in our hiring
pipeline already have 10 years of professional experience

suggests to me that you're not giving these people enough credit. With that level of experience they have no doubt been on at least one (probably both) sides of an interview more than once.
They're going to understand the soft rejection for what it is - a "No, we won't hire you".
You're not going to be able to "groom" (to use your own word) someone with that level of experience. If they're worth hiring then they already understand that they are competing against others and may not get hired. They also have enough experience to apply for other positions.
Your company is not make or break for them. The manner in which they get rejected also won't change their opinion of your company, as long as it is professional. Hilmar is right - you're massively overthinking this.

You are correct, people who are applying for jobs fall into the following categories:

Unemployed, need a job now.
Soon to be unemployed, need a job now
Need to switch jobs, need a job soon
Feeling like they might change jobs, if this application doesn't result in an offer that is fine.
Just looking, no hurry at all.

There is one other type of candidate: Internal candidates who might fall into one of the other groups.

what to do with candidates which are clearly not a fit for a position
(one way or another). With a very strong push from other team members,
that in this case we should "nurture" them for the potential possible
future chance in x, y years. That this would also build 'good brand
image' etc.

This is a great thing to tell internal candidates. Giving them a path forward assuming that they aren't about to lose their job with your company.
Ask your company: how many people did they call back 12 moths later when a new position opened up?
There is nothing stopping them from doing this today. They can take every application that made final interviews 9 to 15 months ago, compare them to all the open positions, and reach out to them with an invite to the final round interview for that position. Don't invite them to reapply, don't do a phone screen unless they want to talk to you.
They should then do the same for people who were just a little short of experience.
The best part about this is that sometimes their job status has changed in the last year.
Candidates rarely believe the things that they are told when they are being rejected. Telling them you will keep their application on file, but never calling anybody back means little to the person rejected.

There is one complication to doing this depending on location. In some jurisdictions (GDPR comes to mind) it may not be legal to keep records of unsuccessful applicants on file, or use them for headhunting, without the prior permission of the applicant.

I went through a hiring cycle in the fall of 2023, and while I managed to secure a job rather quickly, I saw a lot of companies that I would describe as "unempathetic."
If you want to be empathetic in your hiring process, you need to take your candidates seriously, which to me means:

Get back to them soon after you receive their resume (positive or negative)
Run a relatively minimal and speedy interview process (e.g. no eight rounds of interviews or a giant take-home assignment)
Keep them in the loop on how the process is proceeding
Make a decision relatively soon after their interview (again, positive or negative).

I got rejection emails from companies that I applied to literally a year after my application, which is nonsense. Overall, I agree with everyone else that applicants aren't really interested in your mentoring them (unless you are Facebook or Google), but treating applicants with respect will be highly empathetic.

It doesn’t make any sense. You hire me, or you don’t hire me. You can tell me why you don’t hire me - because you need things I don’t have, because I was the second best of two candidates. You can tell me that you would keep my name and contact information for future opportunities.
But why would you want to mentor me, and why would I want to be mentored by you? I want a job, get paid for doing good work, and learn things that I want to learn, not you.

The most employers do (which is also honest) is to tell the applicant

That they have not succeeded
Why they haven't succeeded.
The Company will keep their details on file for future.
The Company is willing to mentor them (for no charge) to help them.

I have often related the first three points to candidates that were my 2nd and 3rd choices.
I feel that the applicants will respond better if they are told promptly and if the Company is honest with them.

While I agree completely with you about the need to be honest with applicants, I think your colleagues have a good point about nurturing applicants for future possibilities. I have a suggestion that might address your concerns and achieve their goals.
Set up a mentoring program where a few very experienced employees offer to occasionally chat 1:1 with people who are early in their careers. They can give them practical advice on what technologies would be worth learning to make them more employable, or help them improve their interviewing skills. The goal would be to help them advance their careers and gain goodwill for the company. Another benefit for the company is that a few of these people might become employees in future. And the mentors will benefit too. I'm recently retired, and mentoring has been very rewarding. You don't realise just how much real life knowledge you have to share until the person you're mentoring asks you questions!
When you reject a candidate but you think they have potential, when you reject them you can invite them to participate in the mentoring program if they'd like. Most people won't take the opportunity; perhaps they have other job prospects they want to focus on.
In this way, you're clear that you're rejecting the candidate, but you're also see something in them you'd like to help nurture. No need to raise (possibly false) hopes about a future job with your company.
